# C#: Convert Byte array into a float

Tags: c#, floating-point, arrays

I have a byte array of size 4

```
byte[] source = new byte[4];
```

Now I wanted to convert this source into a 4-byte float value...

Can anyone tell me how to do this...

Comment: In what numeric format is the byte array?  There are many different ways it might be interpreted.  Do you have an example?  For instance, the bytes of a 32-bit integer, least significant byte at byte 0, each byte little-endian.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Try

`float myFloat = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(mybyteArray, startIndex);`

Comment: Suppose the bytearray came over a network. Is Endianness a concern here? If I wanted to write the sequence of bytes in C or C++ what should I do?

Comment: @mazzaa Yes it is a concern: in case System.BitConverter.IsLittleEndian does not agree the network source, you have to swap the 4 array bytes first