# Converting 4-byte OLE (VB6) to double/float in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, arrays, ole

Well, I have a 4 (four) bytes array that I need to convert to double data-type (or float) in C#.
I believe that the 4 bytes array is an OLE Automation one.

Tried the following, but *no* success:

```
// 1st trial:
double d = BitConverter.ToDouble(b1, 0); // after resizing b1 to be an 8-byte array and padding with zeroes
// 2nd trial:
Int64 lng = BitConverter.ToInt64(b1, 0); // after resizing b1 to be an 8-byte array and padding with zeroes
double d = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(lng);
// 3rd:
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(b1, 0); // no resizing, just as is 4-bytes
```

Tried to reverse the bytes order, but still nothing!

These are sample data:

```
byte b1 = new byte[] {255, 255, 252, 65};
byte b2 = new byte[] {10, 188, 248, 238};
byte b3 = new byte[] {0, 20, 168, 98};
byte b4 = new byte[] {0, 1, 79, 52};
```

I also still have this Cpp code that is supposed to do the process:

```
/*
*********************************************************************************
Simple routine to return four bytes from a buffer (MSB ...  LSB) as a double, signed value
*/
double get_four_byte_double(unsigned char *b){
    double  d;

    d = (double)(((((((((unsigned int)b[0])&0xFF)<<8) | ((unsigned int)b[1])&0xFF) << 8) | ((unsigned int)b[2])&0xFF) << 8) | ((unsigned int)b[3])&0xFF);
    if (d >= max_thirty_two_bit_integer){
        d -= thirty_two_bits;
    }
    d /= 256.0;

    //Return the value we have computed
    return(d);
}
```

Help would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**
Values of Cpp thirty_two_bits and max_thirty_two_bit_integer:

```
static double thirty_two_bits = 65536.0 * 65536.0;
static double max_thirty_two_bit_integer = 65536.0 * 65536.0 / 2.0;
```

**Edit (2):**
Unfortunately I can not find the actual values for the sample data, but I am sure they are in the range: 0-7000 or 0-15000.

Comment: You've given us the sample data, but no indication what the values are meant to be. Without knowing what results you're getting and what you were expecting, it's hard to help you. Given your C++ code, it looks like actually it's just converting it to an *integer*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Convert Byte array into a float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619664/c-convert-byte-array-into-a-float)

Comment: There's no way the cpp code works properly since it's or'ing bytes 0, 1 and 2 together due to the wrong amount of shifting.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not get the actual values of the samples, but I am sure they are in the range of 0-7000 or 0-15000.

Comment: Dear Arion, I have tried the answer you're linking to, but no success, It is already the 3rd trial in my question!

Comment: @AMS OLE marshaling is actually very well defined, it's based on COM and tends to use `SAFEARRAY`. However, what is not clear here is what you are intending to marshal or what the interface is. More than likely the default C# marshaller is more than up to the task of talking to your VB6 code. But without the details of the call it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: @AMS: If you claim that the C++ code already works, then surely you can find the right values that way. Ultimately I don't think you'll have much luck getting an answer without some concrete input to expected output samples.