# Converting bytes to float (C#)

Tags: c#, floating-point, byte, wav

I'm currently working on a WAV(.wav audio file) reader, that reads audio data from a .wave file and creates a waveform.

My problem is, I get a different amount of bytes depending on the "bits per sample" size.

Bytes depending on "bits per sample":

```
8bit = 1 byte
16bit= 2 bytes
24bit= 3 bytes
32bit= 4 bytes
```

For example: 
I read a 24bit stereo .wav file. 24bit/2channels = 12bit = 3bytes per channel. 
The bytes are ordered by **little-endian**.

Starting at byte 44 of the .wav file(where the audio data starts) I read all bytes till the end of the file and pack 3bytes into a sample.
A sample holds the amount of bytes(depending on the bits per sample).

My output looks like this:

```
Sample1 R: 66,65,1
Sample1 L: 66,65,1

Sample2 R: 216,132,2
Sample2 L: 216,132,2
...
```

Question:
*How is it possible to convert different amounts of bytes into a float?*

```
4bytes -> float
3bytes -> float
2bytes -> float
1byte  -> float
```

(Not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619664/c-convert-byte-array-into-a-float) because I don't always have 4 bytes available)

Greetings,
er4zox

Comment: You also need a dynamic range. Given that you just need to apply a _conversion function_ ax+b. For a raw (unscaled) representation just fill an int (or a long for higher bits per sample) and then cast to float directly. If, instead, you want a normalized value (+/-1) in float then do proportion with maximum value for 8~32 bits

Comment: try 
`float myFloat = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(mybyteArray, startIndex);` where startindex is the number of bytes you want to store

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: Convert Byte array into a float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619664/c-convert-byte-array-into-a-float)

Comment: @Takarii no, it needs 4 bytes (always) and they must be a valid floating point number, it does not perform any _conversion_. If you have 16 bit you can't/shouldn't do it (actually you must not do it even if you have 4 bytes because **representation** is different).