# How to read a 16 bit register if I'm getting float value in it using NModbus4

Tags: c#, modbus-tcp

I'm using NModbus4 to read a 16-bit register which already has a float value in it. I'm getting this float value directly from respectively relevant software with registers configured for those float values. 
This register configuration helps me to get recorded value in my console program using NModbus4.

**Question** is quite simple. Nmodbus returns `ushort[]` for  Holding registers and I want to get a float value while reading from response.

Yes, I tried reading two 16-bit registers and fusing them to form float value(32-bit) and NO, I'm not getting desired results.

For example `2.3e-007` results to `0` and number larger than `ushort` datatype results into `32767`. Maybe I need to change something in library(NModbus4). Just some hint would do the trick. Please can anybody help me?

Here is my code snippet:

```
TcpClient masterTcpClient = new TcpClient(address.ToString(), portNo);
ModbusIpMaster master = ModbusIpMaster.CreateIp(masterTcpClient);//Created master

ushort[] inputs = null;
inputs = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, numInputs);//Read Registers

GetRegistersByNModbus(inputs, startAddress);//Convert registers to float
private static void GetRegistersByNModbus(ushort[] inputs, ushort startAddress)
    {
        List<float> floatList = new List<float>();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length;)
        {
            float temp = ModbusUtility.GetSingle(inputs[i++], inputs[i++]);
            floatList.Add(temp);
        }
        float[] floatArray = floatList.ToArray();
        int startReg = int.Parse(startAddress.ToString());
        for (int i = 0, j = startReg; i < floatArray.Length; i++, startAddress += 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Register {0}={1}", startAddress, floatArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without knowing more details, it is diffcult to guess, what's going wrong. When you have to read a float, something/somebody writes it before. Is there a documentation, how it is written? Did you test to exchange the loword and hiword? What is your source code to combine the two words into a float?

Comment: @KBO I'm using ReadHoldingRegisters() method to read holding registers from 0101 to 0131. After providing startAddress, Slave id and noofregisters to read, it reads 0101 to 0131 registers and provide its value in ushort as expected. But not desired. From 0101 to 0131 each register contains a float value thus ushort give 0 when 2.3e-007 is desired and 32767 when number is out of ushort range. 0101 to 0131 registers are getting their values(write) from automation software. We just need to access those values

Comment: Are the floats single-precision IEEE-754?  Assuming so, you'd need to read in 2 ushorts, store them in 4 bytes, being careful to get the order correct, then use something like `BitConverter.ToSingle()` to translate them to a float.  I assume you're already doing similar; can you add some actual non-working code you're using to your question?

Comment: The comment by @sellotape should be the answer. You may have to try all possible combinations of arranging the two ushort values to the 4 byte array (swapping the words and event swapping the bytes within each word) as there is no universal agreement how to encode float in Modbus.

Comment: @sellotape ALL my Code is working. And that's the problem. Because each register is 16-bit but assigned to 32-bit float values written by automation software. While reading each register at a time I'm getting those float values read as ushort. Hence, the above conversion problem. I've already implemented what you said about `BitConvertor.ToSingle()` but it will combine two successive registers which I don't want. I just want value of one register into float. Could reconfiguring registers in feed from Automation software to 32-bit from 16-bit get me anywhere?

Comment: @SamratMatte - sounds like you have _half-precision_ floats then, rather than single.  Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759848/convert-byte-array-to-16-bits-float).