# Convert Two Bytes to Half Float In C#

Tags: c#, precision

How can I convert two bytes (Hi, Lo) into this custom half float implementation using c#?  Its slightly different to other implementation, as it has 9 bits of precision. I've tried modifying this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37761168/14515159  to suit the spec below, but its not converting correctly.

From a protocol sniffer Application
HO = 0x41, LO = 0xC5 should give value of 3.7695313.
However I have not been able to confirm this. The outputs should be in the range of 0 to 5 and all my conversions are way off.

```
 public static float toTwoByteFloat(byte HO, byte LO)
        {
            var intVal = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[] { HO, LO, 0, 0 }, 0);

            int mant = intVal & 0x07ff;
            int exp = intVal & 0x7e00;
            if (exp == 0x3c00) exp = 0x3fc00;
            else if (exp != 0)
            {
                exp += 0x1c000;
                if (mant == 0 && exp > 0x1c400)
                    return BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes((intVal & 0x8000) << 16 | exp << 14 | 0x7ff), 0);
            }
            else if (mant != 0)
            {
                exp = 0x1c400;
                do
                {
                    mant <<= 1;
                    exp -= 0x400;
                } while ((mant & 0x400) == 0);
                mant &= 0x7ff;
            }
            return BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes((intVal & 0x8000) << 16 | (exp | mant) << 14), 0);

            
        }
```

Below is information from custom protocol that I'm working with.

Note for image below that in this protocol document they refer to Bit 0 as the MSB.

[Half Float](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zICSU.png)

> This format can represent numbers from 231 to 2-31 with 9-bits of precision. A zero is represented with >a mantissa and exponent of zero. The exponent is biased with 31 and the mantissa assumes a left most >leading 1. This definition exactly matches the IEEE floating point formats, except the range of the >fields has been reduced.
> Converting from IEEE-754 32-bit format to the 16-bit format is done by splitting the IEEE number into >its component parts: sign, exponent, and mantissa. The mantissa is right shifted 14-bits, losing that >resolution. The exponent is then unbiased (IEEE-754 uses a bias of 127) and re-biased with 31. The 16->bit format is then assembled from the original sign bit, the new exponent, and the new mantissa. During >the re-biasing of the exponent under flow and overflow is detected. Underflows should result in positive >zero. Overflows should result in the maximum possible exponent.

Comment: **having trouble getting it working** what is your problem? post some code so we can better help you

Comment: In general the way this site works is that we help you with *your* programming problems. We don't write code for you. What operations do you expect to do with this numeric type? You really need to show us *your* code. If not, your question is likely to be closed pretty quickly

Comment: Post update with code

Comment: "its not converting correctly": can you give some concrete sample input, expected output and observed output?

Comment: I've added an example conversion, however, I have been unable to confirm this yet.

Comment: Note that BitConverter is dependent on the endianness of the platform. E.g. `BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[] { HO, LO, 0, 0 }, 0);` looks like the wrong order on x86 platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Working with a colleague, we came up with the solution below that converts correctly

```
    public static float Parse16BitFloat(byte HI, byte LO)
    {
        // Program assumes ints are at least 16 bits
        int fullFloat = ((HI << 8) | LO);
        int exponent = (HI & 0b01111110) >> 1; // minor optimisation can be placed here
        int mant = fullFloat & 0x01FF;

        // Special values
        if (exponent == 0b00111111) // If using constants, shift right by 1
        {
            // Check for non or inf
            return mant != 0 ? float.NaN :
                ((HI & 0x80) == 0 ? float.PositiveInfinity : float.NegativeInfinity);
        }
        else // normal/denormal values: pad numbers
        {
            exponent = exponent - 31 + 127;
            mant = mant << 14;
            Int32 finalFloat = (HI & 0x80) << 24 | (exponent << 23) | mant;
            return BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(finalFloat), 0);
        }
    }
```