# Convert Float to array of N x bits, then from array of N x bits back to Float?

Tags: c#, floating-point, byte

I am looking for a way to encode a float value as a array of bits where the length of bits can be specified.

I have found ways of encoding a 32 bit float to 16 bit byte array using the **sample code for Half-precision floating point conversation according to IEEE 754-2008 standard** that I found from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759848/convert-byte-array-to-16-bits-float/37761168#37761168). It works wonderfully for encoding floats as 16 bit binary data.

Using that encoding I was able to reduce the throughput by 50% without any noticeable loss in quality. But I really would like to know if its possible to encode a float as a 12 bit binary array, or even 10 bit? I'd really be interested in a way to even specify the exact number of bits of precision. Is variable precision possible? Would performance be a factor?

Here's a example of two ideal functions that encode a float into a byte array and back to float but allow specifying the precision of the bits within the byte array:

```
//sudo code:

//Encoding:
n = 12; //12 bits precision (number of bits to represent the float) 
float myFloat = 7.777777; //the floating point value to encode as 12 bit array
bytes = ConvertFloatToBytes(myFloat, n); //encode

//Decoding:
float myFloat = ConvertBytesToFloat(bytes, n); //decode
print(myFloat); //the decoded float value 7.777000 (some loss..)
```

I have little knowledge regarding converting floats to bits and vice versa. Glancing at the IEEE 754-2008 sample code was definitely beyond my understanding or ability to modify it. Search results have not been very informative either, I want to continue researching or try to prototype a function but I'm not sure where to begin.

I was hoping someone could provide advice or even possibly a solution on how to encode a float *in c#* as a array of bits of length n, then array back to a float?

Comment: Are you sure a 12-bit float can hold more precision than the decoded value?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format says that a 16-bit float can hold a precision of 65504 plus an exponent and you are trying with 4 less bits.

Comment: For a 12 or 10 bit float, how big would the mantissa be, and do you need a sign bit?