# What is the type of this 4-byte data?

Tags: vb.net

So I've got this piece of data here I'm trying to edit with a program.

The data consists of 2 single floats, then two unknown 4-byte data types and lastly a 32 bit int.

Here's the data in hex: `00 00 C8 41 00 00 70 41 00 20 00 00 7D 12 00 00 0A 00 00 00`

After conversion they should be these numbers:

```
25.0 (float)
15.0 (float)
45 (???)
16 (???)
10 (int)
```

Please tell me what I'm missing or how to convert this.

Note: I'm just trying to convert the 2 unknown 4 byte data. I know how to convert integers and floats.

Edit: Here are some more known values of the same type:

```
00 40 00 00 -> 90
E3 18 00 00 -> 35
00 00 01 00 -> 360
55 15 00 00 -> 30
```

It has to do with angles/degrees of some kind.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you edit them (the unknown bytes) if you don't know what they are?

Comment: Are you sure they are two values four bytes each?

Comment: How do you know that the resulting values for those datatypes are 45 and 16?

Comment: They should be 4 bytes each, yes. I know what they are because there's a program that converts this exact piece of data but doesn't convert it back. It also has no source available so I'm making my own editor. However I don't have a clue what kind of data these values are, or how to convert them back and forth.

Comment: Just to state the obvious, if the last 32 bits (`0A 00 00 00` ) is equal to the integer `10` then you know you are dealing with little endian and you can (probably) assume the rest should be treated that way, too.

Comment: `It has to do with angles/degrees of some kind` - might be a variation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_scaling#Binary_angles

Comment: If it's `Little Endian DCBA` then this converts out to this... `25, 15, 1.147944, 6.632346, 1.401298` In short it's `Little Endian your converting`... On the other hand for `Big Endian ABCD` then these are much different for example: `7.183757, 4.026911, 2.938736, 1.21292055, 6.162976`

Comment: @GSerg is right. It is some kind of angles system. 360 degrees is 65536, 180 degrees is 32767, 90 degrees 16384 and so forth. Now I just need a way to edit this properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not clear what you have done and what is needed to be done. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619664/c-convert-byte-array-into-a-float). You can convert your byte using [System.BitConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx). Are you sure it's 16 and not 26 for your second angle?

```
    Dim data() As Byte = {&H0, &H0, &HC8, &H41, &H0, &H0, &H70, &H41, &H0, &H20, &H0, &H0, &H7D, &H12, &H0, &H0, &HA, &H0, &H0, &H0}

    Dim f1 As Single = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(data, 0)
    Dim f2 As Single = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(data, 4)
    Dim s1 As Int32 = CDbl(System.BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 8)) / 65536 * 360
    Dim s2 As Int32 = CDbl(System.BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 12)) / 65536 * 360
    Dim s3 As Int32 = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 16)
```

Then you just need to do the reverse to get your bytes

```
    s1 = 180.0 / 360 * 65536

    Dim bytes() As Byte = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(s2)

    For Each b As Byte In bytes
        Console.Write(b.ToString("x"))
    Next
```

Now if your problem is opening the file, write the file or something else. Than it wasn't very clear to me.

Comment: Damn my bad. It indeed should be 26. And your formula works. Thanks a lot.