# Casting raw bytes to float is changing values of bytes? C#

Tags: c#, floating-point, bit-manipulation, endianness, ieee-754

I'm casting raw bytes to a single precision float in the same way that I always have done for uint32s and int32s without issue. The problem is that this seems to change the actual value of the float. I have read that C# treats 32bit floats as IEEE754, and IEEE754 calculators agree with my raw bytes returned as a hex string rather than C#s interpretation of the float. Could someone please explain my misconception and how to fix it? I assume it is not an endianness problem since I can't seem to make the bytes match no matter what pattern I try on paper.

```
Score = (Single)(packetBytes[1187] << 24 | packetBytes[1186] << 16 | packetBytes[1185] << 8 | packetBytes[1184]); // strange result
HexStringScore = BitConverter.ToString(new byte[4] { packetBytes[1187], packetBytes[1186], packetBytes[1185], packetBytes[1184] }); // expected result
HexStringCSharpFloat = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(Score)); // strange result
```

HexStringScore: 45-F2-5B-BC (raw data)

Score: 1.173511E9 (wrong, According to Calculators number should be 7755.466796875)

HexStringCSharpFloat: B7-E4-8B-4E

In summary why wont my app understand that 45-F2-5B-BC is 7755.466796875

Comment: What exactly do you expect from first line of code that casts `int` to `float`? You seem to know that BitConverter to be used for conversion... `BitConverter.ToSingle((new byte[] { 0x45, 0xF2, 0x5B, 0xBC }).Reverse().ToArray(),0)` seem to produce what you want - why could not you use it?

Comment: Without answer to why you decided to use casting to convert it is not possible to help you with what misconceptions you have... So [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619664/c-convert-byte-array-into-a-float) answers the rest... If you [edit] the post to narrow down what exactly you don't understand it may be re-opened.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Ok. So doing bit shifts << with or '|' assigns the value to an int first?

Comment: Goku - your code is casting an expression `(….)` to `Single` - which is the reason why portion inside parenthesis is evaluated first (which happen to be whole bunch of int operations producing integer value) and then that result is cast to `float`.